# Looking for high computing, low storage serveres

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, cpu, cloud-hosting

I'm looking for hosting companies that have servers with high computing power and low storage. For example, 10vCPU and 5gb of storage.

Most companies have plans in which the storage grows proportionally with the number of vCPUs. We need more CPU and almost no storage.

Any recommendation?

Thanks!!

Comment: Amazon Web services

Comment: Which AWS service?

Comment: EC2 for computing power and S3 for storage requirements.